# Aliases in /etc/profile.d not present in bash

Tags: aliases

Aliases set in /etc/profile.d are present in a bash shell as expected when I log in to the server using ssh. When starting a new bash shell the aliases are not there. This is a major problem since logging in using NX to get a desktop, there is no possibility to get the aliases since to get a terminal any user need to start a new bash shell.

### The system is RH ES 5.5.

Christer

Comment: .profile stuff gets executed ONLY at a login.....not between different shell invokations.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to show up on a shell invocation it needs to go in `/etc/bashrc`. The `/etc/profile.d` directory is for logins (`su -`, or `ssh` into the box). Check out the **INVOCATIONS** section of the bash man page if you want more info on the differnces.

Comment: Comment to slm (the "Add Comment" function gives uknown erro):
Thank you for your answer. The Invocation section doesn't say anything about that /etc/bashrc is executed when starting an interactive shell. Adding traces to /etc/bashrc shows that it is not executed. So, my simple question is: is there any possibility to add world-wide aliases for interactive shells?